# Amazon Kendra Connector to Internal git pages website

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-kendra

I tried connecting to our company's internal Git project  https://github.x.com/pages/folder/some-repo/ to Amazon Kendra but I’m encountering errors.

I tried creating 2 types of connectors, Web Crawler and GitHub, but both are facing the same problem.

A. A plain web connector with no authentication:
I’m encountering the following error – “Error connecting to customer repository: Web Crawler connector error code: WC-5001 Error message: Could not connect Web Crawler, Error occurred while testing connection with given seed URLs. Couldn't connect to any seed URL from the given configuration. Exception from method: Please enter valid seed URLs.”

B. The Second connector was github based.
Changed the project URL to the source https://github.intuit.com/folder/some-repo

1. Created a GitHub token.
2. Created a new Secret in Secret Manager with the above token.
3. Added secret manager access policy to my role.
4. Referenced these in the GitHub connector
   Still encountering errors: Error connecting to customer repository: Invalid URI

Do you have any ideas?